# I am not allowed to purchase Tech B unless already a customer of System A from same Company, which I do not want/need ..legal?

Tags: united-states, commerce, commerce-clause

A computer system is listed for sale on a company's website with the caveat that I must already be a customer of their gene sequencing platform, which I am not interested in / do not need, as I do not work in this field of study. The computer system is not a promotional or discounted item, nor is it in any way dependent upon the sequencing hardware for it to function.

The computer system is 100% standalone is advertised separately from the sequencing platform.

Is this "full line forcing"? is this acceptable / legal business practice?

Comment: Are you a business or a consumer?

Answer (score 2):

### This is freedom of contract

The company sells one product to everyone, System A.

The company also sells Tech B to only its pre-existing customers.

That is not [bundling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_(antitrust_law)) under the general ideas of antitrust law or [Product Bundling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_bundling) under competition laws, as you don't have any secondary items, and two wholly distinct sales.

The company offers its products separately. The best equivalent would be a line in a restaurant menu that lists "extra patty for your burger" that is only sold as an option for your Hamburger [but not alone](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/85611/10334). Just rephrase the offer to "Tech B for our customers of System A".

There might even be reasons why Tech B is not offered on its own and can't be bought by non-customers of System A. The most simple would be that Tech B is pre-installed with System A - but it is not bundling because you already need to *own* System A to buy Tech B and Tech B is not offered as *machine that can run system A* but *machine set up to run System A* - which is not a bundle but a different product, just like gluten-free cake is to normal cake.

### Nothing forbids negotiating

That doesn't mean that legally you can't get the Tech B: you just would need to negotiate with them for it, outside of the normally offered items.